# Get notification when process has started

Tags: android, process

If I need to run an outside executable, for ex. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sleep 10")`

Is there a way of knowing when the process has started?

Comment: I believe you can make use of ActivityManager

Comment: @Keerthi Ramanathan But I don't have its pid

Comment: You can get the running tasks and services using ActivityManager and then iterate over them to find out your process.This is just my view.